# Why would Randall be out of a job?

Tags: plot-explanation, monsters-inc

In Monsters Inc.  Boo fights back against Randall and gives Sulley a chance to grab him by the throat and restrain him.  Boo roars at Randall as Sulley holds him and Sulley says something like:

> She's not a afraid of you anymore.  Looks like you're out of a job,
>   pal.

Randall then gulps.

They had a case earlier of a child not being afraid of a monster and they just shredded that particular door.  Each monster has a stack of children they work with so why would Randall be out of a job because one child is not afraid of him?

Comment: Maybe it was just a small joke by *Sulley*, it doesn't have to mean that he will really lose his job.

Comment: I thought that too but Randall gulped in response to the comment which would imply that it is more than an off the cuff quip.

Comment: After Randall doing evil things (Almost Through the whole MOVIE!)
i think he is fired during the end of the film.

Comment: Well he is banished by Sully and Mike but that is not just because Boo is not scared of him. It is because he is a murderous psychopath and they needed to put him out of action

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible that Sully was just telling Randall that he was no longer scary anymore to Boo; technically, I don't think Randall would have been out of the job since he could scare other kids. However, Waternoose was arrested; and Randall might have been implicated with Waternooses's scandals, especially if that corporation learned about that scream-sucking machine...

Comment: True but he makes two statements, one that 'she's not scared of you anymore' and then he also states that Randall is out of a job.  If he had just been talking about Boo not being scared of him why add the extra line?

Comment: I don't think it's a second line ... more of a continuation of the first. More like there is a semi-colon between the two instead of a period. _She's not a afraid of you anymore; looks like you're out of a job, pal._